# gen_tcp send io error

Tags: sockets, erlang

I try to send data with gen_tcp:send:

```
gen_tcp:send(Socket, <<"Test message">>).
```

but get error:

```
** exception exit: {badarg,[{io,format,[<0.31.0>,"~p~n",<<"4">>]},
                            {erl_eval,do_apply,5},
                            {shell,exprs,7},
                            {shell,eval_exprs,7},
                            {shell,eval_loop,3}]}
     in function  io:o_request/3
```

How can i fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the error message I'm guessing you have done this:

```
io:format("~p~n",gen_tcp:send(Socket,<<"Test message">>)).
```

you need to wrap your call inside a list. i.e.

```
io:format("~p~n",[gen_tcp:send(Socket,<<"Test message">>)]).
```

See the io module documentation for details on why.